# Delete picture from a cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a new picture in a cell using macros but before copying new picture how can I checked that particular cell already having picture or not, Matching **shape.TopLeftCell** with current cell is **not working** for me, Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
' this is not working for every picture
Sub DeleteCell(curcell) 'curcell=ActiveWindow.ActiveCell

Dim sh As Shapes

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = curcell.Cells.Address Then
         sh.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Best to show your not-working code, and describe in what way it's not working.

Comment: @Haider you need to change `Dim sh As Shapes` to `Dim sh As Shape` and then it works. I called it with with the following line: `Call DeleteCell(Range("B2"))`

Comment: Still not working some shapes are deleting but I want to delete shape from current cell

Answer (score 6):

1. Change `Sub DeleteCell(curcell)` to `Sub DeleteCell(curcell As Range)`
2. Change `Dim sh As Shapes` to `Dim sh As Shape`
3. Change `curcell.Cells.Address` to `curcell.Address`

So your code looks like this

```
Sub DeleteCell(curcell As Range)  'curcell=ActiveWindow.ActiveCell
    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = curcell.Address Then sh.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code if you need:

```
Sub deleteImage()
    Dim Pict As Shape
    Dim Cel As Range
    Set Cel = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F12")
    Dim Caddress As String
    Caddress = Cel.Address
    For Each Pict In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes 'Check for each picture in the range
        If Pict.Type = msoPicture Then
            If Pict.TopLeftCell.Address = Caddress Or Pict.BottomRightCell.Address = Caddress Then
                Pict.Delete
                Exit Sub
            Else:
                MsgBox "Doesn't exists a picture in the range"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next Pict
End Sub
```

Comment: Its showing "Doesn't exists a picture in the range" although picture is there in the current active cell

Comment: @Haider Nope, if an image not exists in the range, doesn't matter if is in `TopLeftCell` or in `BottomRightCell`, displays the message.